# How to use onActivityResult in Kotlin? (UPDATED)

Tags: android, kotlin

I have two activities A and B. A is the homepage and when the plus button is clicked it goes to B where there are two edit texts (question and answer). When both are inputted it and the check button is clicked, it is taken back to A where a new button appears with the text set to the inputted question. I have an inflated view which allows the user to edit the question and answer when clicking the button. The problem is that when I try to use intent to go back to activity B, the previously inputted texts are gone. I tried to use onActivityResult but its not working. Does anyone have any insight?

UPDATE:
I'm going to put my updated code below. I figured out how to send inputs between each activity and now each dynamically created button saved the individual pairs of edit texts. The problem I'm running across now is that it only saves the edit texts once and doesn't allow me to change it again. I've tried bundles, intent and shared preferences but somehow none of them have been working. I thought that having my intents at the top would allow me to save my data every time I inputted text but it isn't working. Here is the code I've been using:

Activity A:

```
    package com.example.yesh

import android.app.Activity
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Gravity
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val questionActivityCode = 2
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.btn2).setOnClickListener{
            startActivityForResult(Intent(this@MainActivity, SecondActivity::class.java), questionActivityCode)
        }

    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == questionActivityCode && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            createNewButtonWithText(data?.getStringExtra("test") ?: "", data?.getStringExtra("test2") ?: "")
        }
    }

    private fun createNewButtonWithText(text: String, s: String)
    {
        val newbutton = Button(this@MainActivity)
        val layout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.mainlayout)
        newbutton.text = text
        newbutton.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        newbutton.width=1010
        newbutton.height=300
        newbutton.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
        newbutton.translationX= 65F
        newbutton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"))
        newbutton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#250A43"))
        layout.addView(newbutton)

        val inflator = layoutInflater
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        val intent1 = Intent(this@MainActivity, SecondActivity::class.java)
        intent1.putExtra("test", text)
        intent1.putExtra("test2", s)

        newbutton.setOnClickListener{
            val dialogLayout = inflator.inflate(R.layout.text, null)
            with(builder) {
                setTitle(newbutton.text)
                setPositiveButton("Edit"){dialog, which ->
                    startActivity(intent1)
                }
                setNegativeButton("Delete"){dialog, which ->
                    layout.removeView(newbutton)
                }
                setView(dialogLayout)
                show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Activity B:

```
package com.example.yesh

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)

        val question = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.question)
        val answer = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.answer)

        val value = intent.getStringExtra("test")
        question.setText(value)
        val value2 = intent.getStringExtra("test2")
        answer.setText(value2)


        findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.btn3).setOnClickListener {
            val questiontext = question.text.toString()
            val answertext = answer.text.toString()

            saveData()

            val returnIntent = Intent()
            returnIntent.putExtra("test", questiontext)
            returnIntent.putExtra("test2", answertext)
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent)

            finish()
        }
    }
    private fun saveData() {
        val question = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.question)
        val answer = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.answer)
        val txt = intent.getStringExtra("test2")
        answer.setText(txt)
        Toast.makeText(this, "Data saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: onActivityResult is used to send the data back to the previous activity(activity A in this case). If you want to send preserve data in SecondActivity then you have to send the data through intent when creating SecondActivity.

Comment: you are creating a new intent to start activity `B` in `createNewButtonWithText(text: String)` you can put your data in that intent and then show it in activity `B`

Answer (score 1):

remember `finish()` in the `B` activity? It destroyed that activity already so there is not way to going back to it again, when you press the new button in activity `A` it and call
`startActivityForResult(intent, 1)` you are creating new instance of that activity , this new instance doesn't know about one which is already destroyed so you should also send the data in the intent which you want to display

Comment: I'm just kind of confused on how to do this. I thought I already sent my intent data in my onActivityResult in Activity B. I know how to send it to A too but I don't know what to do with that data there

Comment: an activity is not a singleton think about it as an object say an object glass (activty) if you filled water in one class (your data) and crated other glass which is empty how can you i already filled that glass with water , think is a new glass get it? `startActivityForResult(intent,1) is creating  a new object of activity the old one was destroy when you called `finish()`

Comment: hey so I actually figured it out. The only problem I'm having now is that once I input my text it stays there. I can't edit it. It doesn't change when I input new text. I tried multiple different methods but so far nothing has worked. I updated my script if it would be ok with you having a look!

Comment: i am glad one of your problem is solved,  now you have some other problem , i think you should ask another question for that , and if you think you were answered for this one you can mark it answered, have a good day

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Abhinav's answer, You cannot access an activity you destroyed with "finish()" as it removes the activity from memory.

The correct way of using onActivityResult() is for cases like fetching data from another activity.
For example, you have a form in Activity A and and there is a field called location. for that you can open Google maps in Activity B and when it is selected, you can return the location in activity A and display in already existing view in A.